# Resize specific chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

I am attempting to make a simple dashboard type of page. I am using Highcharts for the visualizations. To implement layout I am using jQueryUI sortable, specifically the portlet like example. I need to be able to resize a specific "portlet" and have the chart inside resize to fit. I a doing this with the highcharts setSize function. The issue is that I can have and unlimited amount of these "portlets" on the page and I need the correct one to resize based on which "portlet" size is changed.

my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="portlet">
            <div class="portlet-header">Bar</div>
            <div class="portlet-content" id="b_container"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="portlet">
            <div class="portlet-header">Pie</div>
            <div class="portlet-content" id="Pie_Container"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="portlet">
            <div class="portlet-header">Line</div>
            <div class="portlet-content" id="L_container"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="portlet" >
            <div class="portlet-header">Gauge</div>
            <div class="portlet-content" id="g_container"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="portlet">
            <div class="portlet-header">Time Chart</div>
            <div class="portlet-content" id="t_container"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
    </html>
```

and the JS to fill some widgets:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".column"
    });
    $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
      .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
        .end()
      .find( ".portlet-content" );

    $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
      $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });

    $( ".column" ).disableSelection();

    //pie chart
    $('#Pie_Container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: '#232323',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
    //line chart
    $('#L_container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
    //gauge
         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        renderTo: 'g_container',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]        
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

    },
    // Add some life
    function(chart) {
        setInterval(function() {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal, inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);

    });
    //bar chart
     var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
        categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
        name = 'Browser brands',
        data = [{
                y: 55.11,
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'MSIE versions',
                    categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                    data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
            }, {
                y: 21.63,
                color: colors[1],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Firefox versions',
                    categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                    data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                    color: colors[1]
                }
            }, {
                y: 11.94,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Chrome versions',
                    categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                        'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                    data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                    color: colors[2]
                }
            }, {
                y: 7.15,
                color: colors[3],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Safari versions',
                    categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                        'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                    data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                    color: colors[3]
                }
            }, {
                y: 2.14,
                color: colors[4],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Opera versions',
                    categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                    data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                    color: colors[4]
                }
            }];

    function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
        chart.series[0].remove(false);
        chart.addSeries({
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: color || 'white'
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();
    }

    var chart = $('#b_container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                            if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
                            } else { // restore
                                setChart(name, categories, data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: colors[0],
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y +'%';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var point = this.point,
                    s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'% market share</b><br/>';
                if (point.drilldown) {
                    s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
                } else {
                    s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
                }
                return s;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: 'white'
        }],
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        }
    })
    .highcharts(); // return chart
    //time chart
    $('#t_container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Snow depth (m)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.x) +': '+ this.y +' m';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
            // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
            // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
            // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  9), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 16), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 28), 0.67],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  1), 0.81],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  8), 0.78],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 12), 0.98],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 27), 1.84],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 10), 1.80],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 18), 1.80],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 24), 1.92],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2,  4), 2.49],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 11), 2.79],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 15), 2.73],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 25), 2.61],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  2), 2.76],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  6), 2.82],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 13), 2.8 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4,  3), 2.1 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 26), 1.1 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  5,  9), 0.25],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  5, 12), 0   ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Winter 2008-2009',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 18), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 26), 0.2 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  1), 0.47],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 11), 0.55],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  8), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 15), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  1), 1.38],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  8), 1.48],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 21), 1.5 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 12), 1.89],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 25), 2.0 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  4), 1.94],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  9), 1.91],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 13), 1.75],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 19), 1.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 25), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 31), 0.35],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  5,  7), 0   ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Winter 2009-2010',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9,  9), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 14), 0.15],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 28), 0.35],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 12), 0.46],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  1), 0.59],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 24), 0.58],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  1), 0.62],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  7), 0.65],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 23), 0.77],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2,  8), 0.77],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 14), 0.79],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 24), 0.86],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  4), 0.8 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 18), 0.94],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 24), 0.9 ],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 16), 0.39],
                [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 21), 0   ]
            ]
        }]
    });
    $(".portlet").resizable({
    resize: function() {
        chart.setSize(
            $(this).width() - 10,
            $(this).height() - 60,
            false
        );
    },
    maxWidth: 301,
    minWidth: 301
    });
});
```

At the end of the JS you can see where I am attempting to set up the drag and resize but it is not quite working right. No matter which widget I drag only the top left widget resizes. How do I set it up so that only the specific widget I am resizing changes?

Comment: Here is a fiddle to see http://jsfiddle.net/XHLdp/

Comment: When any of `.portlet`s gets resized, you call `setSize()` on the very same chart - the one that was assigned last to the `chart` variable. What you need to do instead is determine which chart resides in the `.portlet` currently being resized, and call `setSize()` of that particular chart.

Comment: I follow what you're saying but I am unsure how to code that, any hints? even if it is something I need to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments, you have to determine correct chart to resize depending on current `.portlet` being resized. I have no experience with Highcharts, but this seems to work in your jsfiddle:

```
$(".portlet").resizable({
    resize: function() {
        $(this).find('.portlet-content').highcharts().setSize(
            $(this).width() - 10,
            $(this).height() - 60,
            false
        );
    },
    maxWidth: 301,
    minWidth: 301
});
```